# Which class is capable of dealing the most damage?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I remember reading in Mass Effect guides that the infiltrator class was capable of dealing the most damage in a given amount of time (DPS) in  the first game. I think that has probably changed by now, so I'd like to know what's the current state of affairs. Since facing insanity will be no easy feat, I'd like to push odds in my favor.

Which class in ME3 can be optimized to achieve the highest DPS?

Comment: this would depend on if the DPS is on a single target or multiple targets, against armor or shields, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page is for building a class and weapons.
http://narida.pytalhost.com/me3/classes/#20KLPLAT9%400%40E%40%40N4a4%400%400

The damage charts have **1st** Sniper **2nd** Shotgun **3rd** Pistol **4th** Assault **5th** SMG. (the sniper is only 30 points higher.) Geth Infiltrator for Sniper   the N7 Destroyer Soldier class for everything else

**Sniper** Javelin X

**Damage: 3698.33**

1545.8 (base value)
+25% (386.45) High-Velocity Barrel V
+25% (386.45) Extended Barrel V
+2.5% (38.65) Networked AI 1
+2.5% (38.65) Networked AI 2
+7.5% (115.93) Networked AI 4
+10% (154.58) Networked AI 6
+30% (463.74) Sniper Rifle Rail Amp III
+15% (231.87) Sniper Rifle Amp V
* 10% (336.21) Geth Weapon Damage Bonus

**SHOTGUN**
Claymore X

**Damage: 3666.8**

1648 (base value)
+25% (412) High-Velocity Barrel V
+25% (412) High Caliber Barrel V
+5% (82.4) T5-V Battlesuit 1
+5% (82.4) T5-V Battlesuit 3
+7.5% (123.6) T5-V Battlesuit 4
+10% (164.8) T5-V Battlesuit 6
+30% (494.4) Shotgun Rail Amp III
+15% (247.2) Shotgun Amp V

**Pistol**
Talon X

**Damage: 1668.68**

702.6 (base value)
+25% (175.65) High Caliber Barrel V
+40% (281.04) Heavy Barrel V
+5% (35.13) T5-V Battlesuit 1
+5% (35.13) T5-V Battlesuit 3
+7.5% (52.7) T5-V Battlesuit 4
+10% (70.26) T5-V Battlesuit 6
+30% (210.78) Pistol Rail Amp III
+15% (105.39) Pistol Amp V

**Assault**
Saber X

**Damage: 1056.23**

534.8 (base value)
+25% (133.7) Extended Barrel V
+5% (26.74) T5-V Battlesuit 1
+5% (26.74) T5-V Battlesuit 3
+7.5% (40.11) T5-V Battlesuit 4
+10% (53.48) T5-V Battlesuit 6
+30% (160.44) Assault Rifle Rail Amp III
+15% (80.22) Assault Rifle Amp V

**SMG**
Hurricane X

**Damage: 253**

128.1 (base value)
+25% (32.03) High Caliber Barrel V
+5% (6.41) T5-V Battlesuit 1
+5% (6.41) T5-V Battlesuit 3
+7.5% (9.61) T5-V Battlesuit 4
+10% (12.81) T5-V Battlesuit 6
+30% (38.43) SMG Rail Amp III
+15% (19.22) SMG Amp V

Answer (score 2):

Sentinels are a great mix between Engineers and Adepts. Being a Sentinel allows you to offset some of the negatives of being an Engineer, by giving you better shield and more offensive powers. If you want to be able to strip enemies of their shields from afar and then run in with your almost impenetrable shields to blast unprotected enemies away, then the Sentinel class for you.I myself am a soldier but I think Sentinel is the best!

Comment: +1 because I think Sentinels are the most fun to play with. Vanguards are supposed to be the ultimate badasses though.

Comment: @kotekzot I can attest to vanguards being badasses in ME3

Answer (score 2):

The absolutely highest single damage attack you can do in the game can be achieved with this setup:

1. Infiltrator /w max cloak
2. A maxed out [M-98 Widow](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-98_Widow) with 2 max level damage mods.
3. Max out Operational Mastery for damage and head shots
4. Take the Warp Ammo squad power and max it out for single target damage/head shots
5. Wear armor that boosts weapon damage
6. A head shot

I believe this is the highest achievable damage in the game, this setup will let you 1 shot any normal enemy and take out a big chunk of health/armor on any big enemies.

Comment: If you're in single player, make sure to take the Weapon Damage broker terminal upgrades when they become available, too.

Answer (score 2):

I find the following set up for a Human Engineer to be working well:

- Human Engineer
- Incinerate with area blast upgrade
- Overload with both chain blast upgrades & shock organics upgrade
- Drone with shield/attack boost and chain attack upgrade
- Assault Rifle (M8 Avenger X has been doing fine for me)
- Cryo ammo upgrade

You are not dealing high damage to a single target, but instead dealing huge damage distributed amongst enemies at once.

Your crowd control, hitting groups of enemies at once, further boosted by the Cryo ammo allowing you to easily set up frozen targets for Tech Combos with Incinerate, again nuking areas of predamaged opponents.

I can clear, or at least hold off, whole hordes single handed if need be.

Its also a very team play orientated build, as your thinning the herd making it easier for other to to pick off wounded foes, slowing down enemies for Infiltrators to headshot, stripping shields for Vanguards to massacre in Bitoic charge, and the drone is great for holding the attention of larger foes whilst you collectively pond them - seriously - target a drone on a Banshee or Brute and watch them stand and fight it!

Answer (score 1):

I find using a soldier, with

- Concussive shot maxed
- Ammo power adapt upgrade
- Upgraded incendiary

Upgraded incendiary can deal massive amounts of area damage, especially if you have 200% cooldown rate from lightweight weapons; even on insanity difficulty.

Answer (score -1):

On earth (insane), another solution is to work with companions that do primary damage on armor with James (set it to melee build with high resistance) and Garrus. Set them to use automatic powers (in game options) While your primary job is to strip shields and support your team. If you do this correctly, you start to have a good team work and relatively good immersive play. I think for an immersive game. From I have see, if you work correctly, your companions can regulary share automatically combo with you without micro managing them.